# Spring REST - validating primitive GET request parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest, spring-validator

Is there a way to validate primitive (int, String etc.) GET parameters using annotations?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/{someInt}",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> someRestApiMethod(
    @PathVariable
    @Valid @Min(0) @Digits(integer=10, fraction=0)
    int someInt) {

    //...

    return new ResponseEntity<String>("sample:"+someInt, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

As you see I have put a bunch of annotations to validate someInt to be a positive integer with 10 digits but still it accepts every kind of integers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Given the following controller:

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class ValidatingController {

    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    public int validatedPath(@PathVariable("id") @Max(9) int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    public String constraintViolationHandler(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
        return ex.getConstraintViolations().iterator().next()
                .getMessage();
    }
}
```

and a `MethodValidationPostProcessor` registered in your context as follows (or XML equivalent, and not necessary with the Spring Boot web starter - it will do this for you):

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

Assuming your dispatcher servlet is mapped to `http://localhost:8080/`:

- accessing `http://localhost:8080/9` gives `9`
- accessing `http://localhost:8080/10` gives `must be less than or equal to 9`

It looks like [moves are afoot](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6380) to make this easier/more automatic in future versions of Spring.

Answer (score -1):

As per JSR 303 this is not possible. See [this](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303#2) for details

Comment: Simply sharing a link without describing what portion of the reference link mentions about the topic of the question, doesn't make sense. Moreover I have gone through the JSR303, and nowhere does it say that path variables cannot / should not be validated.